# Redirect https://domain.com to https://www.domain.com in Godaddy

Tags: redirect

Redirection from http://domain.com to  https://www.domain.com is achieved by using godaddy forwarding, but not able to achieve it for https url. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this by going to your domain manager and adding a forwarding.

Set up a domain forwarding and forward requests to https://yourdomain.com